# Do fighter pilots have to manually input the ordnance they have loaded on the aircraft?

Tags: military, fighter

When ordinance is loaded onto a fighter or bomber, does the system automatically know what ordnance it has? Or does the pilot have to manually input for each pylon?

Answer (score 16):

On the B-52G and H models (at least in the 80s when I worked on the simulator) weapon loading was part of the data read into the Offensive Avionics System preflight, from a digital tape cartridge.

> MISSION DATA LOAD

> The FMS provides a method for the user to load a sortie and a mission data file from the DTS. Up to eight
> sorties can be resident on a DTC. Each sortie contains
> up to nine B-52 missions. Mission data consist of a set
> of up to 99 pre-planned destinations, 99 fixpoints, 42
> OAPs and data required by the weapon SMOs for release of weapons at one or more of the destinations.
> The resident sortie or mission, if any, can be viewed
> on the Mission Supervision Display, CF-8, or the Mission Data Load Display, CF-81. To load a sortie and
> mission see Mission Supervision Display this section.

> SMO LOAD

> FMS allows the operator to load multiple Stores Management Overlays (SMO) into memory and select one
> of the loaded SMO to be the Primary SMO. For each
> possible weapon location one SMO can be loaded. The
> CF-62 display shows all the SMO available from the
> DTS, indicates which (if any) of these SMO are already loaded, indicates which SMO (if any) is the primary SMO, allows the operator to modify what SMO
> are loaded, what location(s) each SMO is to control,
> and allows the operator to select a SMO to be the primary SMO. To load SMOs and designate a primary
> SMO see SMO Load Menu (CF-62) this section.

Acronymology:

- DTC Digital Tape Cartridge
- DTS Digital Tape System
- FMS Flight Management Software
- OAP Offset Aimpoint
- SMO Store Management Overlay

Source: [Radar Navigator’s/Navigator’s
Manual USAF SERIES B-52H AIRCRAFT](https://www.scribd.com/document/602400929/Boeing-B-52H-Navigators-Manual), page 1-134

Answer (score 13):

This depends on the aircraft in question, but current F-16 and above get programmed with whatever load they are carrying. The pilot does not have to do it manually.

There is a Common Central Interface Unit (CCIU) the ground crew programs when they load the aircraft.

https://www.centcom.mil/MEDIA/igphoto/2001694833/

Comment: Just to clarify - this still means that someone manually inputs the loadout either via computer or data cartrige right? The plane won't "autodetect" what's hanging on the pylons?

Comment: What can be the reasons of not using "smart" ordnance with a basic identification feature (mechanical, optical, data exchange, etc). A printer knows the model of ink cartridge inserted, a camera the lens used, an oscilloscope the probes connected, a computer the USB device plugged, etc? Why not using this plug and play model for ordnance? Lack of standardization?

Comment: @Mavrik - Some munitions can tell the aircraft what they are, some cannot. AIM-9 vs AIM-120 on a wingtip launcher, it can tell the jet. MK-82 (500lb) vs MK-84 (2000lb) dumb bomb...there is no data connection. The aircraft can know "something" is there. But not what.

Comment: @mins - Not everything is "smart". A Triple Ejector Rack (TER), with 3x MK-82 dumb bombs looks, to the jet, exactly the same as 3x 25lb BDU-33 practice bombs.

Comment: Thanks. Related: [MIL-STD-1760 Aircraft/Store Electrical Interconnection System](https://quicksearch.dla.mil/qsDocDetails.aspx?ident_number=37120)

Comment: @mins I could see reliability being an issue. If somehow the avionics detect no munitions or incorrect munitions, then it may be impossible to deploy them. Also the same munitions may be loaded onto aircraft with very different avionics packages from very different manufacturers. Of course new contracts could specify standards, but it would take a few decades for enough aircraft and munitions to be refreshed to make the standards actually standard. Which is not to say it's not a good idea. Maybe it's just not been seen as a good *enough* idea for change to happen.

Comment: @ToddWilcox see also *Red Storm Rising* where an maritime patrol aircraft is scrambled in a hurry and missed a config detail, making the weapon un-fireable, and were unable to deliver the killing blow to their prey.  I'm sure Clancy based that on real world experiences… So manual systems are not 100% reliable either.  Something like the BDU-82 vs 84 could be simply magnets on the launch bracket.  Cheap and simple, like how cassette tapes detected chrome or metal.

Comment: "What can be the reasons of not using "smart" ordnance with a basic identification feature (mechanical, optical, data exchange, etc)"   Easy to answer. Military stuff has to be reliable.

Comment: Of course, the fact that much of the weapons technology (and outright ordnance) dates back from 1980s also makes a difference.

Comment: @Mavrik - Even earlier. Current "smart bombs" are mostly Vietnam era bombs, with a guidance unit on the front, and steerable fins on the back. The GBU-12 Paveway II is literally that, a 500lb Mk-82 general purpose bomb, with bolted on "smarts". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBU-12_Paveway_II

Comment: @ToddWilcox It wouldn't be hard to retrofit existing ordnance and aircraft with identification systems.  The sophisticated stuff needs a data connection anyway, that leaves just the dumb bombs and the laser guide bombs (dumb bombs with a laser seeker) to identify.  That's not a lot of bits, a strip of metal with/without magnets at certain locations would do fine.

Comment: @Fattie So long as the pilot can override the detection it would be more reliable than not having it.  And if you put decent error detection in your encoding it would be pretty hard to have a weapon come up misidentified.  Malfunctions would be along the lines of "unknown store", the pilot would know what he should be carrying.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel - There is little need to make mods to have ALL of the munitions self identify. There is a large body of information that various segments of the ground crew have to preload anyway. IFF code, radio freqs, etc, etc. The weapons loadout is just one more

Comment: @LorenPechtel "It wouldn't be hard to retrofit existing ordnance and aircraft"... a mere trillion dollars and decade of effort!

Comment: @fectin Depends on how much they manage to milk it.  I'm saying it would technically not be that hard, it would just be a small piece fastened to the bomb and the reader on the airplane.  An easy retrofit, nothing needs to be replaced.

Comment: @LorenPechtel if you don't know what drives this to be hard, you are probably not ready to have opinions on whether things are easy.

Comment: @fectin I agree that from a standpoint of actually getting it done the bureaucracy would make this very hard.  That's a political problem, though, not a technical one.